# how to use type suggestions to specify an argument can only take values from a list of options

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

Say a Python function has an argument `option` which can only take specific values, say either `option_a` or `option_b`. How to specify this as a type annotation? Here is an approach that doesn't work:

```
def f(x, option: Union['option_a', 'option_b'] = 'option_a'):
    if option == 'option_a':
        print('option is option_a')
    elif option == 'option_b':
        print('option is option_b')
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'invalid option: {option}')
```

It doesn't work because `Union['option_a', 'option_b']` will actually look for classes `option_a` and `option_b` as opposed to interpreting them as literals.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of Union and Literal for this:

```py
def foo(s: Union[Literal['a'],Literal['b']]):
    print(s)

foo('a')  # good
foo('b')  # good
foo('c')  # error
```